# Multiple conditions for Select Case using ChassisType

Tags: vbscript, case, computer-name, mdt

We use MDT in our environment to image computers. We are using a script in order to name computers based on IP location and the script then writes the data to a database. I need to modify the script to include a section of additional conditions to construct the computer name. I am having difficulty with the portion that uses the additional condition of Chassis type in the script below.

The portion I need help with is

```
Case (InStr(1, strIP, ".111.")>0),(strChassisType = 8,9 Or 10)
  strSiteCode="UKL"
Case (InStr(1, strIP, ".112.")>0),(strChassisType = 8,9 Or 10)
  strSiteCode="NYL"
Case (InStr(1, strIP, ".113.")>0),(strChassisType = 8,9 Or 10)
  strSiteCode="HKL"
```

I would like to have these three conditions work and set the site code based on the condition of Site and then chassis type, but I am not sure how to use multiple conditions or how to combine the chassis type and would like guidance.

Following is the full script

```
Function UserExit(sType, sWhen, sDetail, bSkip)
  oLogging.CreateEntry "entered UserExit ", LogTypeInfo
  UserExit = Success
End Function

Function computerName()
  'On Error Resume Next
  Dim strSerial,strAsset, strManufacturer, strIP, strSiteCode
  Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
  Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  '----Establish SQL Connection----
  Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  objConnection.Open "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=XXXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=NetMetrics;User Id=netmetrics;Password=*********;"

  '----Determine local Service & Asset Tags----
  strComputer = "."
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

  Set colSMBIOS = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_SystemEnclosure")

  For Each objSMBIOS In colSMBIOS
    strManufacturer = objSMBIOS.Manufacturer
    strSerial = objSMBIOS.SerialNumber
Next

  '----Determine Site Code based upon IP address----
  Set IPConfigSet = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled=TRUE")

  For Each IPConfig In IPConfigSet
    If Not IsNull(IPConfig.IPAddress) Then 
      For i = LBound(IPConfig.IPAddress) To UBound(IPConfig.IPAddress)
        strIP = strIP + IPConfig.IPAddress(i)
      Next
    End If
  Next

  Set colChassis = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_SystemEnclosure")

  For Each objChassis in colChassis
    For Each strChassisType in objChassis.ChassisTypes
      Select Case strChassisType
        Select Case True
          Case (InStr(1, strIP, ".111.")>0)
            strSiteCode = "UK"
          Case (InStr(1, strIP, ".112.")>0)
            strSiteCode = "NY"
          Case (InStr(1, strIP, ".113.")>0)
            strSiteCode = "HK"
          Case (InStr(1, strIP, ".111.")>0),(strChassisType = 8,9 Or 10)
            strSiteCode = "UKL"
          Case (InStr(1, strIP, ".112.")>0),(strChassisType = 8,9 Or 10)
            strSiteCode = "NYL"
          Case (InStr(1, strIP, ".113.")>0),(strChassisType = 8,9 Or 10)
            strSiteCode = "HKL"
        End Select

  If (inStr(1,strManufacturer,"Dell")) Then
    strSQLQuery = "select count(*) from AssetTags where ServiceTag='" & strSerial & "'"
    priorEntry = objConnection.Execute(strSQLQuery)
    If priorEntry(0) = 0 Then
      strSQLQuery = "select right(concat('00',right(max(assettag),3)+1),3) from AssetTags where AssetTag like '" & strSiteCode & "[^S]%'"
      Set arrNewTag = objConnection.Execute(strSQLQuery)
      strSQLQuery = "INSERT INTO AssetTags Values ('" & strSerial & "','"& strSiteCode & arrNewTag(0) & "', 'New')"
      objConnection.Execute(strSQLQuery)
      computerName=(strSiteCode & arrNewTag(0))
    Else
      strSQLQuery = "select assettag from AssetTags where ServiceTag='" & strSerial & "'"
      Set arrNewTag = objConnection.Execute(strSQLQuery)
      computerName=(arrNewTag(0))
    End If
  Else
    computerName = "Set Computer Name"
  End If

  objConnection.Close
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You don't seem to specify what is wrong with the code, what errors are you getting, or what is the expected result. This will make it unlikely to attract high-quality answers to your question.

Comment: Edits above. I thought I was clear that I was having a difficult time with the multiple conditions of Chassis type. I don't know how to combine them properly. The script is not returning a result, and it is an error of "Expected ')"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use multiple conditions in a `Case` statement you need to connect them with logical operators unless you want to match any of them (the comma means you have a list with several independent conditions).

A statement

```
Select Case True
  Case x=1, y=2
    ...
End Select
```

matches if `x` has the value 1 or `y` has the value 2.

A statement

```
Select Case True
  Case x=1 And y=2
    ...
End Select
```

matches only if `x` has the value 1 *and* `y` has the value 2.

However, personally I consider this an abuse of `Select` statements since they're normally meant to branch depending on different values of one variable or expression.

```
Select Case x
  Case 1
    'do some
  Case 2
    'do other
  Case Else
    'didn't expect this value
End Select
```

I prefer `If..ElseIf..Else` statements for checking multiple different conditions.

```
If x=1 And y=3 Then
  ...
ElseIf x=2 And y<5 Then
  ...
ElseIf y>2 And z-x=4 Then
  ...
Else
  ...
End If
```

**steps off soapbox**

With that said, in your case you'd never even get to the three additional checks, because one of the first three conditions would've matched first. You'd need to put the combined conditions before the simple conditions to make your statement work. Also, you can't check a variable against multiple values like this:

```
strChassisType = 8,9 Or 10
```

What you can do is use comparison operations like this if your values are numeric:

```
If strChassisType >= 8 And strChassisType <= 10 Then
```

do a dictionary lookup:

```
chassisTypes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
chassisTypes.Add  "8", True
chassisTypes.Add  "9", True
chassisTypes.Add "10", True
...
If chassisTypes.Exists(strChassisType) Then
```

or define a `Contains` function to check for the presence of a value in an array:

```
Function Contains(a, v)
  Contains = False
  For Each e In a
    If e = v Then
      Contains = True
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Function
...
If Contains(Array("8", "9", "10"), strChassisType) Then
```

Since your second set of conditions would basically just modify the result of the first set of conditions I'd probably do exactly that: modify the result of the first set of conditions. And maybe use `Split(strIP, ".")` for splitting the relevant subnet from the IP address.

```
subnet = Split(strIP, ".")(2)
For Each objChassis In colChassis
  For Each strChassisType In objChassis.ChassisTypes
    Select Case subnet
      Case "111": strSiteCode = "UK"
      Case "112": strSiteCode = "NY"
      Case "113": strSiteCode = "HK"
      Case Else
        WScript.Echo "Unknown subnet: " & subnet
        WScript.Quit 1
    End Select

    If strChassisType >= 8 And strChassisType <= 10 Then
      strSiteCode = strSiteCode & "L"
    End If
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Awesome breakdown and explanation of the problem.

Comment: This was fantastic and allowed me to not only have a solution, but understand the process for finding that solution and where I was wrong in my initial attempt. Thank you.